# What does a proof show that the covariant derivative is a $(1,1)$ tensor?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, tensors, vector-fields, general-relativity

The covariant derivatives of a vector field $X^a$ is given by

$$\triangledown_bX^a = \partial_bX^a + \Gamma_{bc}^aX^c$$

Why does showing that the RHS of this is equal to

$$=\frac{\partial{\widetilde{x}}^c}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial{x}^b}{\partial \widetilde{x}^d}(\partial_c \widetilde{X}^d+\widetilde{\Gamma}_{ce}^d\widetilde{X}^e)$$

does this prove that the covariant derivative is a $(1,1)$ tensor? I cannot see how the last equation helps prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine an arbitrary $(1, 1)$ object $A^a_b$. This is object is said to be a tensor if transforms as a tensor, in your notation

$$
A^a_b = \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^a}{\partial x^c} \frac{\partial x^d}{\partial \tilde{x}^b} \tilde{A}^c_d \tag{1}
$$

It is important to emphasize here that something with indices is not necessary a tensor (e.g. $\Gamma^{a}_{bc}$ is **not** a tensor). But if it transforms as a tensor then that's a whole different story.

Noe compare (1) with your expression. It is clear that the object $\nabla_bX^a$ transforms as a tensor.

Comment: no, I cant see that because a) mine equation only has upper indices and b) how does your equation prove its a (1,1) anyway

Comment: @Permian Are we talking about the same object? $a$ is an upper index and $b$ a lower one. What do you mean by "only has upper indices"?

Comment: $(\partial_c \widetilde{X}^d+\widetilde{\Gamma}_{ce}^d\widetilde{X}^e)$ the X's

Comment: I cant see what the $\widetilde{A}_d^c$ corresponds to in my case

Comment: @Permian The thing in parenthesis in your second equation has two free indices: $c$ and $d$

Comment: but the c is only a partial derivaitve and the d is on the gamma term which isnt a tensor?

Comment: @Permian $c$ is not a partial derivative it is an index, and so is $d$, but you shouldn't care about in what context they appear, as long as the object they appear in transforms as a tensor, it is a tensor

Comment: ok thanks @caverac